# openCV.framework for a swift macOS application

Tags: swift, macos, opencv, frameworks

My goal here is to have opencv embedded in macOS application as static framework. I clone the [repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)

```
cd opencv/platforms/osx
python build_framework.py  build
```

Then i get the following error

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileC platforms/osx/build/build/build-x86_64- 
macosx/modules/world/OpenCV.build/Release/opencv_world.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/opencv- 
onnx.pb.o modules/dnn/misc/onnx/opencv-onnx.pb.cc normal x86_64 c++ 
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
============================================================
ERROR: Command '['xcodebuild', 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12', 'ARCHS=x86_64', '-sdk', 
'macosx', '-configuration', 'Release', '-parallelizeTargets', '-jobs', '16', '-target', 
'ALL_BUILD', 'build']' returned non-zero exit status 65
============================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/Dev/XCode-openCV/please/opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 148, 
in build
self._build(outdir)
File "/Volumes/Dev/XCode-openCV/please/opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 122, 
in _build
self.buildOne(target[0], target[1], main_build_dir, cmake_flags)
File "/Volumes/Dev/XCode-openCV/please/opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 255, 
in buildOne
execute(buildcmd + ["-target", "ALL_BUILD", "build"], cwd = builddir)
File "/Volumes/Dev/XCode-openCV/please/opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 44, in 
execute
retcode = check_call(cmd, cwd = cwd)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", 
line 190, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['xcodebuild', 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12', 
'ARCHS=x86_64', '-sdk', 'macosx', '-configuration', 'Release', '-parallelizeTargets', '- 
jobs', '16', '-target', 'ALL_BUILD', 'build']' returned non-zero exit status 65
```

I give up on this after couple hours. And maybe try to find another route. I find [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U49CVY8yOxw) [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJeP1juuHHY) videos showing how to build the library with the cmake app, which builds and installs opencv at /usr/local/bin. He then opens XCode and points to these files, but he is making a macOS c++ command line app. Is there a way to use this c++ app in a swift app as a library or submodule?